# Java 8 Stream - operations on objects with same id within Collection

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

My question is a bit complex (I think), so I'll try to use an example. Hopefuly you'll understand my problem.

Set's say I have a List of users:

```
List<User> users;
```

Where:

```
public class User{
    private List<Car> cars;
}

public class Car{
    private String code;
    private List<Feature> features;
}

public class Feature{
    private String code;
}
```

What I want to achieve is get the list of Cars from the list of Users BUT I also want this list to be distinct (no cars with the same code) BUT I want the single Car object to have all of the Features from different cars with the same code and that's where I fail.

For now I have

```
List<Car> cars = users
        .stream()
        .flatMap(user -> user.getCars())
        .???
```

I know I can filter cars by code using Predicate but I'm suffering to add features to the ones I'm leaving. Is there a clean way to do it with streams?

Comment: Maybe you fail because “I want the single Car object to have all of the Features from different cars” is a very diffuse specification. How do you expect the `Car` object to have features from other cars and what features are you talking about? Has this anything to do with real life cars?

Comment: there is a way that you could use `distinct()` but that only works if `car.equals(car)` but would require you to have the equals method only work for the car code

Comment: another way you could do, would be to map the code to features, e.g. `Map<String, List<Feature>>`, it wouldn't be a list of cars, but would have the required information you need.

Comment: or finally you write a custom collector, that will check the list for a car with a code, if it doesn't add, that car, if it does, add the features to that car.

Comment: If you create a `public Car mergeFeatures(Car car1, Car car2)` method, you can turn it into a collector, I don't know if that helps solve the entire problem, but it may take you a step closer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It all boils down to the question, how you want to get a `Car` having all the joint features. You surely don’t want to modify an arbitrary `Car` instance of one of the `User`s. Hence, to support joining these `Feature`s you have to construct a new `Car` instance after joining the feature lists.

This can be done as follows:

```
List<Car> cars =
    users.stream()
    .flatMap(user -> user.getCars().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Car::getCode,
        Collectors.mapping(Car::getFeatures, Collector.of(
            ArrayList<Feature>::new, List::addAll, (a,b)->{a.addAll(b);return a;}))))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .map(e -> new Car(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

There are two steps. The first performs a grouping operation using the `code` property as key and joining the `Feature` lists of all `Car`s in a group to one `List`.
This produces a `Map<String,List<Feature>>`. The second step converts each map entry to a new `Car` instance, assuming that there is a `Car(String code, List<Feature> features)` constructor. These result `Car` instances are collected into a `List`.

Note that the code above just joins all `Feature` lists to one list. If you have to eliminate duplicate `Feature`s from these lists you may use

```
List<Car> cars =
    users.stream()
    .flatMap(user -> user.getCars().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Car::getCode,
        Collectors.mapping(Car::getFeatures, Collector.of(
            LinkedHashSet<Feature>::new, Set::addAll, (a,b)->{a.addAll(b);return a;}))))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .map(e -> new Car(e.getKey(), new ArrayList<>(e.getValue())))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This first collects the `Feature`s of `Car`s with the same `code` into a `Set`, eliminating duplicates but retaining the order (for the case it’s relevant) and converts the `Set` into a `List` when constructing the result `Car` instance.

Comment: Thank you for a detailed answer. I've run into a problem using this solution and that's probably because I've described my intention quite poorly. Ideal solution would be to eliminate duplicated Features, as you predicted. There are some errors using this approach in my project:
`The type Set does not define add(Object, Object) that is applicable here` 
`The method addAll(Object) is undefined for the type Object`
`The method setFeatures(Collection<Feature>) in the type Car is not applicable for the arguments (Object)`